# Type coordinates for an object and move all other selected objects accordingly

Tags: transforms

I have a scene with several objects connected to each other. I need to put one of the objects at position (0, 0, 0) and all other objects should follow it keeping the relative offsets. How can I do that?

Comment: you don't want to parent all your object to the one that will go to 0,0,0? If not, you could give them a Child Of constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all of your object while holding Shift. Make sure you select the object you want at the center last.

While all the objects are selected, press Ctrl + P and select "Object".

Now when you move the object that the others are parented to, the rest will move along with it.

Make sure your 3d cursor is in the center by pressing Shift + S, and then selecting "Cursor to center."

Now, select the object you want at the center, press Shift + S, and select object to Selection to Cursor."

Comment: Thanks! Once I've done the move, how can I remove the child relationship and keep the objects position?

Comment: select all the objects that are parented, press Alt + P, and then select "Clear Parent"

Comment: "Clear Parent" will also reset the transformations of the child objects, but there is also a "Clear and Keep Transformation" which clears the parent child relationship but keeps the transformations.